# How do I recover my lost village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a COC level 36 account and I'm playing on my tablet. I downloaded bluestack to my computer and installed COC so that I can play with both my computer and tablet. However, after I linked my level 36 account to the new level 2 account, I lost my level 36 account. I have used my tablet and computer with 1 Google account. How do I get back my level 36 account?

Comment: Sorry. What? Do you have any idea what you're trying to say? | **BlueStacks is an Android emulator, Steam has nothing to do with your GooglePlay account and Steam is bugged when it comes to launching BlueStacks with it.**

Comment: COC states for Clash of Clans? You should add that tag to your question.

Comment: Also, have you logged onto the Google Play through Clash of Clans? (Then in that case, it can be retrieved by logging in)

Comment: Maybe editing your question might help you.

Comment: @Randomizer, done.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/186686/75275) answer:

> As long as your account is linked with Google+ it is safe.
>
> You will be able to access it on Bluestacks (or any mobile device) by entering this Google account again. Just make sure to click the Google+ button once you enter back in the game so that you get your village loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1. When in game, go to options then disconnect on Google account. (Google+)
2. Connect it again.
3. When the Google connects, ( the one with green box ) press back button.
4. It should give you a list of Google accounts, pick the one you want.
5. Confirm then it's good to go.