# How can I load my village back if I am not connected to google?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was playing on my phone but my phone suddenly got reformatted. I cannot load my village as outlined in the answer to [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181997/how-do-i-recover-my-old-game-save) because I was not connected to Google while playing, I was connected using my Facebook account instead.

Is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: As always, send a message to SuperCell

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to restore your information with an iCloud backup (if you've included it in your backup plan and if your using an iPhone).