# What does "using the same Google Play for more than one account" mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans

From [Supercell's Clash of Clans support site](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&s=my-account&f=save-your-progress-with-google-play-1438681635):

> #### Save your progress with Google Play!
>
> Make sure to save in-game progress with Google Play!
>
> Please note that Google Play only supports one game per account! If others would like to start a new game on your device, they must save it to a separate Google Play account. Warning: **using the same Google Play for more than one account will result in lost progress!**

What does "*same Google Play for more than one account*" mean in the above context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my old game save?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181997/how-do-i-recover-my-old-game-save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does "same google play for more than one account" mean in above context ?

This means that Google Play acts as a save account location. You can only save 1 game on your Google Account, usually an @gmail.com address. If you wanted to share the device and have them play separately you will need a second Google Play account. This will prevent losing save files as they are separately stored by Google based on account.

Comment: Is playing 2 seperate accounts on same device safe (account_loose/ban proof)?

Comment: As Google Play Store instructs you to use this option, I say no, it would not result in loss of account or bans.