# village overwritten

Tags: clash-of-clans, ios, android

I have lost my village due to overwritten another village on google play account but I have linked that account with facebook. So can i regain that village using facbook linkup in either iphone or android phone ?

Comment: So you made a new village over your existing one on the same google account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my old Clash of Clans (COC) game save & base?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181997/how-do-i-recover-my-old-clash-of-clans-coc-game-save-base)

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore villages from Facebook, and now that it is overwritten on Google Play Games / Game Center, it is gone forever.